# Products not displayed uniformly in list page

Tags: category-products

In product list page I have set the `column count` for the products as `4`. But the products are displayed as 3 in first column and 4 in next cloumn when there are seven products totally.Normally it should be displayed as 4 in first column and rest in the next column. I tried changing the styles for that. But am stuck here. Unable to figure out the reason.

Comment: you have it in two places one in catalog.xml and one in catalog/product/list.phtml did you change both?

Comment: In list page there is no option like this to change.